# MYSQL select data with predefined values if date not exist in same table

Tags: mysql, database, join, union

I have resutl sql with syntax:

```
SELECT AreaName, Date, Total
FROM table
GROUP BY AreaName, Date
```

Here Result:

| AreaName | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 2021-01-01 | 2 |
| Paris | 2021-01-01 | 3 |
| London | 2021-02-01 | 4 |
| Beijing | 2021-02-01 | 5 |

But I want include AreaName if date data not exist with value Total 0. Like here:

| AreaName | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 2021-01-01 | 2 |
| Paris | 2021-01-01 | 3 |
| Beijing | 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| London | 2021-02-01 | 4 |
| Paris | 2021-02-01 | 0 |
| Beijing | 2021-02-01 | 5 |

Any Advice ?

Comment: Your query has no filtering criteria so what determins which dates are missing? You're not aggregating anything so why are you grouping?

Comment: @Stu I don't want to do any filtering, missing date viewed by missing area, i just want to display the data by date and area, if the area data doesn't exist on a date then, i want to display it as 0.

Comment: So your table only contains rows for two dates?

Comment: @Kendle because London already exist on every date data and paris don't have data on 2021-02-01, and Beijing don't have data on 2021-01-01.

Comment: Without any date range criteria this makes little sense, however you're after a *Calendar table* which you need to outer-join with.

Comment: @Stu no that's just example, date on my table row is dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use sub-queries with DISTINCT to get lists of all dates and all AreaNames and then cross join them.
Warning: this multiplies the values and could quickly create an enormous result set containing a host of zero values.

> ```
> create table Areas(
> AreaName varchar(25),
> AreaDate Date,
> Total int);
> insert into Areas values
> ('London', '2021-01-01',  2),
> ('Paris',  '2021-01-01',  3),
> ('London', '2021-02-01',  4),
> ('Beijing','2021-02-01',  5);
> ```

> ```
> select
>   a.AreaName,
>   b.AreaDate,
>   coalesce(c.Total,0) "Total"
> from
> (select distinct AreaName from Areas) a
> cross join 
> (select distinct AreaDate from Areas) b
> left join Areas c
> on a.AreaName = c.AreaName
> and b.AreaDate = c.AreaDate
> order by AreaDate, AreaName
> ```
>
> ```
> AreaName | AreaDate   | Total
> :------- | :--------- | ----:
> Beijing  | 2021-01-01 |     0
> London   | 2021-01-01 |     2
> Paris    | 2021-01-01 |     3
> Beijing  | 2021-02-01 |     5
> London   | 2021-02-01 |     4
> Paris    | 2021-02-01 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0937543c16d1c29cacfede992d2ac98b)*

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
areas AS ( SELECT DISTINCT AreaName 
           FROM source_table ),
dates AS ( SELECT DISTINCT `Date`
           FROM source_table )
SELECT AreaName, `Date`, COALESCE(Total, 0) Total
FROM areas
CROSS JOIN dates
NATURAL LEFT JOIN source_table;
```

Comment: Hello @Akina : this gives me the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NATURAL JOIN source_table' at line 9` in dbFiddle using mySQL 5.7 or 8.0

Comment: @Kendle Yes, should be NATURAL LEFT JOIN... fixed.

Comment: that's working fine in dbFiddle MySQL 8.0 but 5 doesn't accept CTE, which is why I used sub-queries. Thanks for reminding me of the NATURAL JOIN syntax. I'd forgotten it and it saves typing. Regards Kendle

Comment: @Kendle Nothing prevents to convert CTEs to subqueries. And the query will be like your one - except using natural joining.